# How to unit test a document.ready() function using jasmine

Tags: jquery, jasmine, document-ready

How do you test document.ready block using Jasmine?
To be more specific , if I have a block like this :

```
$(document).ready(
    function () {
        abc = true;
    }
});
```

How do you test that the inner function was called when the document was ready, using Jasmine?

Comment: You don't need to test `$().ready`. `jQuery` has it's own testing, so you can be sure that the function will be called when the document is ready. If you want to implement a broader integration test, that would depend on what your function does. For example, if the function enabled some kind of button, you could write a test that ensured that button was enabled. Your question is really too broad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do you test document.ready block using Jasmine? To be more specific , > if I have a block like this :
>
> $(document).ready(
>       function(){
>      abc= true;
>   }
>   );

My understanding is that code you have written within $(document).ready closure above is not testable. This link has a good explanation of how to make it more testable : http://bittersweetryan.github.io/jasmine-presentation/#slide-17

> How do you test that the inner function was called when the document was ready, using Jasmine?

Answered above by m59 in comment already.

Answer (score 5):

You could refactor your code to be something like this:

```
var onReady = function(){
    abc = true;
}

$(document).ready(onReady);
```

and your tests:

```
it("Tests abc", function() {
    onReady() ;
    expect(tesabctVar).toEqual(true);
});
```

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer, links are for documenting the solution but solutions are more convenient in the answer itself